# Why Data not Saved into database in edit view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC program and when I save changes its not saving the data

This is the controller Index and Edit :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            int HospitalId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["HospitalID"]);
            DateTime sample_date = DateTime.Today;
            var dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS = db.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS
                .Where(x => x.hospital_no == HospitalId && x.DATE <= sample_date).OrderBy(sam=>sam.sample_id).Include(d => d.Department)
                .Include(d => d.Hospital).Include(d => d.LabTests_hajj).Include(d => d.sys_users);
            return View(dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.ToList());
        }

 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            int HospitalId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["HospitalID"]);
            var results = db.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.Where(d => d.sample_id == id && d.hospital_no == HospitalId).ToList();
            return View(results);
            
        }


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Edit(List<DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS> list)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
 
        {
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                var c = db.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.Where(a => a.TEST_ID.Equals(i.TEST_ID)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (c != null)
                {
                   c.TESTS_MORNING = i.TESTS_MORNING;
                   c.TESTS_EVENING = i.TESTS_EVENING;
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("Details");
            //ViewBag.Message("Updated Successfully");
        }
        //ViewBag.Message("Updated Successfully");
        //return View(list);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
    else
    {
        // ViewBag.Message("Failed ! Please try again");
        return View(list);
    }


}
```

This is the Index view markup :

```
@model IEnumerable<warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th> Test  </th>
        <th> morning tests </th>
        <th> Evening tests </th>
        <th> Test Date </th>
       
        <th> Department   </th>
        <th> Hospital </th>
       
        <th> User  </th>
        <th>Sample Day</th>
       
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LabTests_hajj.TestName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TESTS_MORNING)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TESTS_EVENING)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATE)
        </td>
       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Dept_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hospital.hospital_name)
        </td>
       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sys_users.user_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sample_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.sample_id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.SID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.SID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

and this is the EDIT view

```
@model List<warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<h2>Clinical Chemistry Tests</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICSddd", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            @*<td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().LabTest.TestName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().unitidn)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RESULT1)</td>*@
            <td>Test Name</td>
            <td>Morning Test</td>
            <td>Evening Test</td>
            <td>Test Date</td>


        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>


                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].LabTests_hajj.TestName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].TESTS_MORNING)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].TESTS_EVENING)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].DATE  , new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].TEST_ID)</td>


            </tr>
        }
    </table>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:30px;">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    
}
```

I entered tests in morning and tests done in evening shift for each test
I have each day all tests has one sample id and each test has test id

[image]
why when I click SAVE its not save the data I entered what's wrong with code

please help me .

Comment: Debug  the code to see what is happening. And at best also implement some sort of logging to know whats happening when you are not explicitly monitoring the code.

Comment: @Ralf ok I will do

Answer (score 0):

Debug the code and check if the db.SaveChanges() line is reached